# Knockout bindings won't clear/remove

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I have a bootstrap modal defined on an MVC view, see below.

```
<div id="myOpenRequestModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog" style="overflow-y: initial !important;">

    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">TSR Preview Summary</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" style="max-height:800px;overflow-y:auto;">

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-override" style="display:none;">Override</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-override-commit" style="display:none;">Commit Override</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-override-cancel" style="display:none;">Cancel Override</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info tsrcancel" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel Request</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info close-request" data-dismiss="modal">Close Request</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default print-button">Print</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Exit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When the user clicks the "View" button on the grid, it does an Ajax call to get render a partial view's html, return it and populate the body of the modal thru jquery, `$('modalbody').html(htmlreturned);` for example. At this stage, knockout is rendered on the partial for a section of the view and the bindings is called once, see below...

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 left-padding-row">
        Note(s):
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="col-md-10 left-padding-row">
        <table class="table notes" style="margin-bottom:0 !important;">
            <tbody id="NotesGrid" data-bind="foreach:{data: Notes, as: 'note'}">
                <tr data-bind="attr: { index: $index }">
                    <td width="70%">
                        <textarea data-bind="value: note.Value, disable: note.Disabled, attr: { name: 'Notes[' + $index() + '].Value'}" style="width:100%;height:100%;resize: none;"></textarea>
                    </td>
                    <td width="25%">
                        <input class="btnRemove" type="button" data-bind="click: $parent.removeNote, visible: note.IsNew" value="Remove" />
                    </td>
                    <td width="5%">
                        <input class="hdnNoteID" type="hidden" data-bind="value: note.NoteID" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>


var _viewModel = new ViewModel();

function note(index) {
    this.NoteID = ko.observable('');
    this.Value = ko.observable('');
    this.Index = ko.observable(index);
    this.IsNew = ko.observable(true);
    this.ShowID = ko.observable(false);
    this.Disabled = ko.observable(false);
    return this;
};

function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.Notes = ko.observableArray(convertJSONToKoObservableObject());

    //Ko Functions
    self.addNote = function () {
        var index = $('#NotesGrid tr:last').attr('index');
        self.Notes.push(new note(index + 1));
    }

    self.removeNote = function (row) {
        self.Notes.remove(row);
    }
}

//FUNCTION
function convertJSONToKoObservableObject() {
    var json = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model.Submission.Notes))');
    var ret = [];
    var index = 0;
    $.each(json, function (i, obj) {
        var newOBJ = new note(index);
        newOBJ.NoteID = ko.observable(obj["NoteID"]);
        newOBJ.Value = ko.observable(obj["Value"]);
        newOBJ.Index = ko.observable(index);
        newOBJ.IsNew = ko.observable(false);
        newOBJ.Disabled = ko.observable(true);
        newOBJ.ShowID = ko.observable(false);
        ret.push(newOBJ);
        index++;
    });

    return ret;
}

//BIND UP! *UPDATED*
ko.applyBindings(_viewModel, $('.notes')[0]);
```

The above is the code for creating the grid and applying knockout to it. This all WORKS on the first load of the modal with the returned partial views html. If i close the modal and then re-open the same partial view, it bombs out because the bindings already exists. I have tried `ko.cleanNode`, `destroy`, `remove`, etc. Can someone please enlighten me as how to rebind properly in this scenario?

EDIT: For clarification, 1 MVC View containing the modal markup and 1 MVC partial View used for rendering the body of the modal. The knockout code lives on the partial view.

Comment: have you tried explictly binding to an element that is in your partial view .. like ko.applyBindings(_viewModel,$("#inpartialview")[0]); ?

Comment: I have not tried that, i did however try to use clearNode for a single element with no luck on unbinding it. I also did some checks using ko.dataFor to see if things were unbinding and it showed that no matter what i did, the bindings from the first load never go away until i do a total page refresh. (f5)

Comment: If I follow exactly what you are doing .. that is .. when a user clicks something you are using AJAX to populate the content of *modal-body every time* with a result of a partial view from the server, by localizing the binding to an element with in the partial view you can solve your problem. tried to demo my thoughts here : https://jsfiddle.net/b2chwy87/2/

Comment: You nailed it right on the head of what i am doing. I'll give it a shot on your suggestion and come back when i have tested it.

Comment: Alright i made an edit with the idea and it appears to of had an effect. I think my issue is getting the bindings to work for all the pieces of the model. You can see that i tried it with the "notes" class tag but the buttons no longer do anything. This is entirely new to me so i assume i am missing something. This approach however did remove the multiple bindings error which is a step forward...i hope

Comment: OHHHH i see!! just read the documentation on that method to explain exactly what it does..the buttons are outside the search so they don't get bound. Let me update that and see!

Comment: BOOM!!!!! it works :D :D :D :D I had to localize the bindings. If you want to provide the answer i'll mark it as answered. I basically created a container div to wrap all the KO data binds in and then used the localized parameter to search within that container for binding.

Comment: Great!!!! very glad you got it working ... I will compile an answer for future reference, please feel free, if you wish, to edit the answer to make it as relevant to the question as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main source of the issue is that the KO binding definition in the partial view that is loaded via AJAX is globally binding a view model to the container.

A good solution here (even if you don't wish to reload the partial view) is to localize the binding to a container element with in the partial view by using this syntax

```
ko.applyBindings(_viewModel,$("#inpartialview")[0]);
```

This would bind the element with id "inpartialview" to view model and would be very easy to isolate replace if need be and ultimately eliminates the need to do any binding clean up work.